# Update only selected row on asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net

Here is the scenario, I have created a program for time in and time out

a person enters at 7 am and leaves at 2 pm

PERSON A| 7:00 AM| 2PM

Person a enters again at 3pm

PERSON A| 3:00 PM|

when i click the time out button, it will update the time out column, when it does, both timeout of person A will be updated.

here is my code

```
 protected void EMPLOYEERECORD_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
        Label lblEditEmpName = (Label)EMPLOYEERECORD.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblEditEmpName");
        Label lblEditTimeOut = (Label)EMPLOYEERECORD.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblEditTimeOut");
        TextBox txtEditRemarks = (TextBox)EMPLOYEERECORD.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditRemarks");   

        DatabaseModule.SQcon.Open();
        string cmdstr = "update dbo.RecordEmployee set TIME_OUT=@timeout, REMARKS=@editRemarks where EMPLOYEE_NAME =@empname";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, DatabaseModule.SQcon);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", lblEditEmpName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@editRemarks", txtEditRemarks.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeout", DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DatabaseModule.SQcon.Close();
        EMPLOYEERECORD.EditIndex = -1;

        BindData();



    }
```

How can I update only the selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a key to each individual row.

Your example:

```
PERSON A| 7:00 AM| 2PM
PERSON A| 3:00 PM|
```

Your update statement will update all rows that have the same employee name.  Therefore, update for **PERSON A** will update both rows.

If you don't already, you need to create a unique identifier for each row (e.g. an int) that will allow you to update just the specific row.

For example, the table structure could be:

```
1 | PERSON A| 7:00 AM| 2PM
2 | PERSON A| 3:00 PM|
```

And the update statement would change to:

```
update <whatever> where RowId = @rowId
```